# How to develop applications with Xcode for multiple os version?

Tags: xcode, macos

I developed a small application on my mac with osx 10.9. Now I want to share the application with some friends, but not everyone is using osx 10.9. One friend is using for example osx 10.6. How I can make my application compatible? Maybe some of you know some good tutorials for my problem?

Greets!

Comment: My advice, simply build for the oldest version using the latest sdk available for this os version and your good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the deployment target to the lowest OS X version you need to support.

In Xcode, click on your target in the left menu,  General > Deployment Info > Deployment target.

Comment: Can I use multiple Deployment targets? It would be perfect to have one application for more than one osx.

Comment: The Deployment target setting basically means "The oldest supported OS version". An app with Deployment Target 10.6 will work on 10.9 as well. (If you don't use API that has been removed because of deprecation). Make sure to test on all OS X versions you want to support.